# Add an image to a blade.php file correctly

Tags: html, laravel-blade

I'm trying to add an image to a custom 404 not found page. I'm making it and it's not working.
This is my code:

```
<body style="background-color: #F6F6F6">
<div style="text-align: center">
    <img src="../../../public/image/logo.png" alt="">

    <h3 style="color: #557CD5; font-family: Josefin Sans !important; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold;">
        Parece que la pagina que buscas no existe!
    </h3>
</div>
</body>
```

The error I'm getting is:

> GET http://dev.u.com/public/image/logo.png 404 (Not Found)

However, I can see in the public/image folder and the image is there. If I try and do to the link it also says 404 not found.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `../../../public/path` you should `{{asset('path')}}` for resources: it will generate the right absolute path for that resource.

Comment: `<img src="{{ asset('public/image/logo.png') }}" alt="">` like that?

Comment: without 'public/'